# How can I remove a color from a button in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my C# I am changing to color of a button like this:

```
aButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#e9e9e9");
```

Is there a way to remove this color. I know I could set it back to the color it was before but wondering if there is a way to just remove whatever was assigned?

Comment: What do you mean by removing? If you mean transparent, you can assign it to `Color.Transparent`

Comment: I changed it from the default so I was hoping to restore it to what it was. I am wondering where it is set as I assume the color is set somewhere with either Apple or Xamarin code.

Comment: According to the documentation, that should be `Color.Default` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BackgroundColor/

Comment: Done. I also added the hint for transparent color because that might be what others are looking for if they find this question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Xamarin documentation, [the `BackgroundColor` of a `VisualElement` is `Color.Default`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BackgroundColor/).

So you can just assign your `Button.BackgroundColor` property to `Color.Default`:

```
aButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Default;
```

You can't remove a color because it is a **non-nullable value type**. If you instead intend to make it transparent, assign it to `Color.Transparent`:

```
aButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Never knew `Color.Default` existed!

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the background colour of the `Button`. there is no way to *"remove"* the colour. I don't think this exists in any language (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

Your best bet is to reset the Colour:

```
public Color PreviousColour { get; set;}

public void SetColour()
{
    PreviousColour = aButton.BackgroundColor;
    aButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#e9e9e9");
}

public void ResetColour()
{
    aButton.BackgroundColor = PreviousColour;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that some place in the Xamarin Source code they set default colors. Any idea if that's the case?

Comment: @Alan not that I know of. [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) would be where to start. but the code above would be much easier/simpler